# Adding contact into ios addressbook

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I want to add contacts into my address book. I am developing an app where I have gone through many links, and I have following code, but now I am stuck.

I have imported:

```
    #import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
    #import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h
```

in `viewcontroller.m`:

```
-(IBAction)addToAddressbook:(id)sender{
ABUnknownPersonViewController *unknownPersonViewController = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];
unknownPersonViewController.displayedPerson = (ABRecordRef)[self buildContactDetails];
unknownPersonViewController.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:unknownPersonViewController animated:YES];
[unknownPersonViewController release];
}

- (ABRecordRef)buildContactDetails {
NSLog(@"building contact details");
ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
CFErrorRef  error = NULL;

// firstname
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"Don Juan", NULL);

// email
ABMutableMultiValueRef email = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(email, @"expert.in@computer.com", CFSTR("email"), NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty, email, &error);
CFRelease(email);

// Start of Address
ABMutableMultiValueRef address = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
NSMutableDictionary *addressDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[addressDict setObject:@"The awesome road numba 1" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
[addressDict setObject:@"0568" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
[addressDict setObject:@"Oslo" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, addressDict, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, address, &error);
[addressDict release];
CFRelease(address);
// End of Address

if (error != NULL)
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

[(id)person autorelease];
return person;
}
```

In `UI` I have an `IBAction` button connected to `addToAddressbook`, but on click, nothing is happening - so what else to do I need to do in `UI` or in the code?

Comment: try NSLog in addToAddressbook method whether it is being called or not.

Comment: what do you mean by "nothing is happening" , the `unknownPersonViewController` not shown or the record is not inserted,? add a breakpoint n test if `-(IBAction)addToAddressbook:(id)sender` is called or not

Comment: @Bonnie I mean its not moving to any view controller.Actually it should take it to the ADD contact of address book rite??

Comment: ur right, first check if ur `navigationController` is not nil then try and use `[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:unknownPersonViewController animated:YES];` insteasd of push. if it works

Comment: @Bonnie after clicking in debugger it shows **building contact details*** but nothing is happening..am i missing something??

Comment: i asked if `navigationController` is not nil did u check that, and tried `presentModalViewController`.

Comment: @Bonnie can i hv ur id??

Comment: its better we discus here, so that if not me, someone else can help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30533/discussion-between-bonnie-and-abhilash)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code i can see that you are missing the `ABAddressBookSave` statement. After setting the values of

```
// firstname
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"Don Juan", NULL);

// email
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty, email, &error);

// Address
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, address, &error);
```

You should call `ABAddressBookSave` which is as follows.

```
ABAddressBookSave(ABAddressBookRef addressBook, CFErrorRef* error);
```

Comment: the `buildContactDetails:` method is only needed to generate a `ABRecordRef` to be used by the `ABUnknownPersonViewController` the saving part is handled by the `ABUnknownPersonViewController`. no need of saving it here.

Comment: @Bonnie: Thanks for the clarification, i misunderstood this part. Thanks again :)